# Are employers willing to hire someone with bad academic grades?

Tags: job-search

I'm new here and I'm wondering if employers from a major bank would consider hiring someone with no relevant experience and poor academic grades.

I'm trying to apply into the graduate analyst program at a major tier one investment bank and I'm immediately rejected due to the second upper honours requirement.

About myself: Im 26 and graduated from an Ivy League university with a pass degree in life sciences in 2016. During my university days, I founded 2 start ups, 1 of which was acquired by a major oil company. Also, I started a non profit organization based in India, that focused on combating rape and empowering ladies through education. I've attended pitches and acquired a number of investors for this start up.

Are there any comments or experiences from fellow stackexchangers who have gone through similar circumstances? Thank you!

Comment: In all my life I have never had anyone ask me for my grades. They have only asked me for my degree as proof that I actually have one.

Comment: Your question is largely off-topic here as you seem mostly interested in personal career advice. Perhaps the general question "*Do entry level jobs in the US banking sector require academic honours?*" is on-topic but even that is difficult to answer. Frankly, I'd wager that the answer is yes, and that they'll also want a degree in finance rather than biology. "Top-tier" is a pretty clear sign that candidate profiles should also be top-tier which you presumably aren't. If you want stories you need to be on a forum, not a Q&A site.

Comment: In your CV/cover letter, highlight your strengths, not your weaknesses. *I'm trying to apply [somewhere] and I'm immediately rejected due to the second upper honours requirement.* - Don't apply to a place like that.

Comment: If that is what you truly want to do, then go get a Masters degree in finance and /or statistics. Concentrate on getting top grades. Then apply for those types of positions.

Comment: Ivy League <> pass degree / 2nd upper honours. You might want to look at this [academia.SE] question, [How does the admission process work for Ph.D programs in the U.S., particularly for weak or borderline students?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-the-us-particularly). While you're not going for a Ph.D,, some ideas in the answers may be of help.

Answer (score 2):

**no relevant experience and poor academic grades**

It's the combination that's the problem. Your achievements seem to be in areas irrelevant to an analyst position. Try fitting your skills and experience to the job, and if you can't, get some more relevant experience.

Personally, I adapt my CV for each job, highlighting the relevant skills from each previous employment. For example: flipping burgers provided experience in stock control, working to deadlines, hygeine standards, etc...

Answer (score 1):

There is so many applicants that they may pick-up only the best. They can simply cut-off the people that have bad grades. They often use their workers in recruitment process, so for them it is costly to interview or even take a look in the application.

Some may be willing to take a look at your application based on your university, but you probably should take some other approach. For me it seems that you have sacrificed personal interests for that non-profit and to start-ups. Thus it does not seem to me that you have had too good of a strategy for the banking career.